# invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to dynamically insert timestamps with varying hour intervals into Postgres (12.1), NodeJS 10.15.3, and Knex.

Inserting directly into Postgres via Postico, the `NOW() + INTERVAL 'n hours'` format works fine:

```
insert into users (first_name, updated_at) 
values ('Bob', NOW() + INTERVAL '2 hours');
```

When inserting via Knex,

```
row.updated_at = `NOW() + INTERVAL '2 hours'`;
```

I'm getting error:

```
invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "NOW() + INTERVAL '2 hours'"
```

Outputting the query via query.toString(), I see the interval has been converted to

```
'NOW() + INTERVAL ''2 hours'''
```

How can I insert this in the correct format?

Comment: can you please post example code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

knex is converting your input into `string` and passing it to the database, which , it expects, would be parsed by db to be a valid timestamp. To avoid knex wrapping your input in double quotes, you need to specify it as a literal value. And the way to do that is use `raw`

```
row.updated_at = knex.raw("NOW() + INTERVAL '2 hours'");
```

where `knex` is the variable that you used to instantiate connection with the db.